# mysql usage of 'not in' without column value

Tags: mysql

i have a table `Transactions` that looks similar to this:

```
id  Type         Field      ObjectId  NewValue    
1   AddLink      HasMember  4567      someDomain/someDirectory/1231
2   AddLink      HasMember  4567      someDomain/someDirectory/1232
3   AddLink      HasMember  4567      someDomain/someDirectory/1233
4   DeleteLink   HasMember  4567      someDomain/someDirectory/1231
```

The numeric end of "NewValue" is what i am interested in.

In Detail, i need those records where i have a record where type is "AddLink" and where no newer record of type "DeleteLink" exists, i.e. the records with `id` = 2 or 3 (since 4 deletes 1)

The "ObjectId" as well as the numeric bit of "NewValue" both are IDs of entries of the "tickets" table, and i need the relevant tickets.

i tried this:

```
SELECT `Tickets`.* FROM `Transactions` AS `addedLinks`
    LEFT JOIN `Tickets` ON RIGHT (`addedLinks`.`NewValue`, 4) = `Tickets`.`id`
    WHERE `addedLinks`.`Type` = 'AddLink'
        AND `addedLinks`.`Field` = 'Hasmember'
        AND `addedLinks`.`ObjectId` = '4567'

        AND NOT RIGHT (`addedLinks`.`NewValue`, 4) in (

            SELECT `Tickets`.* FROM `Transactions` AS `deletedLinks`
            LEFT JOIN `Tickets` ON RIGHT (`deletedLinks`.`NewValue`, 4) = `Tickets`.`id`
            WHERE `deletedLinks`.`Type` = 'DeleteLink'
                AND `addedLinks`.`id` < `deletedLinks`.`id`
                AND `deletedLinks`.`Field` = 'Hasmember'
                AND `deletedLinks`.`ObjectId` = '4567' )
```

This gives me:

```
SQL Error (1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Unless i got something wrong, the problem is

```
RIGHT (`addedLinks`.`NewValue`, 4)
```

in the "AND NOT ... in()" statement.

Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

[EDIT]
Thanks to David K-J, the following works:

```
SELECT `Tickets`.* FROM `Transactions` AS `addedLinks`
    LEFT JOIN `Tickets` ON RIGHT (`addedLinks`.`NewValue`, 4) = `Tickets`.`id`
    WHERE `addedLinks`.`Type` = 'AddLink'
        AND `addedLinks`.`Field` = 'Hasmember'
        AND `addedLinks`.`ObjectId` = '5376'

        AND NOT (RIGHT (`addedLinks`.`NewValue`, 4)) in (

                SELECT `id` FROM `Transactions` AS `deletedLinks`
                WHERE `deletedLinks`.`Type` = 'DeleteLink'
                    AND `addedLinks`.`id` < `deletedLinks`.`id`
                    AND `deletedLinks`.`Field` = 'Hasmember'
                    AND `deletedLinks`.`ObjectId` = '5376' )
```

but i don't understand why?

Comment: @PetSerAl that results in the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: I think your subselect only wants to select the `id` field, i.e. `Tickets.*` -> `Tickets.id`

Comment: Either replace keyword `IN` with `EXISTS` and remove the `RIGHT (``addedLinks``.``NewValue``, 4)` or change your subquery that it will return only one more column.

Comment: @DavidK-J Good catch! This also solves my problem. Thank you! But i don't really understand why?

Comment: Simply, `IN` requires a list to compare with, so `foo IN ( 1,2,3,4,5 )`. If your subquery is selecting multiple fields, the resulting list is conceptually a list of lists (AoAs) like, `[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']` and it's going to complain at you

Comment: @DavidK-J thank you... that is very plausible, and one might have understood it from the manual... stupid me.
 Care to write that in an answer, so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your sub-select, as you are using it to provide the value of an `IN` clause, your sub-select should only select the id field, i.e. `Transactions.*` -> `Transactions.id`

So you end up with:

```
...
AND NOT (RIGHT (`addedLinks`.`NewValue`, 4)) IN
    SELECT id FROM Transactions AS deletedLinks WHERE
...
```

The reason for this is that `IN` requires a list to compare with, so `foo IN ( 1,2,3,4,5 )`. If your subquery is selecting multiple fields, the resulting list is conceptually a list of lists (AoAs) like, `[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']` and it's going to complain at you =)

Answer (score 0):

Ah that's so complicated and with subquery... make it simpler, will be much faster

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `__del_max`
    SELECT `NewValue`, MAX(`id`) as id FROM tickets
    WHERE type = 'DeleteLink'
        GROUP BY NewValue;

CREATE INDEX _nv ON __del_max(`NewValue`)

SELECT * FROM `tickets` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `__del_max` ON tickets.NewValue = __del_max.NewValue AND __del_max.id > tickets.id
WHERE __del_max.id IS NULL
```

You can have it in single, big join, but it'd be beneficial to have it in TMP table so you can add an index ;)

Comment: I'm using my above statement in a recursive function that is supposed to find children of elements. I'm not comfortable with your suggestion for that job (which does not mean much) but most of all it does not explain what i did wrong?

Comment: Hm... it's very simple, IN can contain many values IN(1,2,3) but only ONE column, eg. IN (x), but NOT - IN (x,y)

If you want to continue your way, you need OUTER JOIN instead.